# Close one of the device screens in assistant editor's preview mode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm testing an app in multiple screen sizes in Xcode's preview mode in the assistant editor. I can add devices but I haven't been able to figure out how to remove the device after I know it is aligned properly. The Main.Storyboard is on the left. You can see in the picture below that the three devices on the right are aligned properly, but now I can't get rid of them and it's a bit crowded. Right clicking doesn't work and neither does the x in the top right corner.

My question is: Is there a command or shortcut on the keyboard that allows us to get rid of that device size once we've tested it? For example, if I wanted to leave the two Iphones on the right but get rid of the Ipad?
[image: Different device sizes on right]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Been there done that... Turns out to be a really easy:

Select the view you wish to delete and press the Backspace button on your keyboard.

Done!

Comment: I swear I tried that earlier, Xcode must have been slow! Well at least everyone knows now! I couldn't find any answers on it! Thanks for the help!